# Failed to send email from command

Tags: linux, email, smtp, command

I’ve used sendEmail (not sendmail) with my surveillance Beaglebone for almost two year and no problem with that. Now when I run:

```
sendEmail -f sender@gmail.com -t recipient@hotmail.com -m "subject" -u "body" -o tls=auto -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu sender -xp senderPASS
```

I got:

```
sendEmail[12501]: ERROR => Connection attempt to smtp.gmail.com:587 failed: IO::Socket::INET6: getaddrinfo: System error
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, simply my Beaglebone was disconnected from the internet.